# How to find the centers of mass of two overlapping objects with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, object, overlapping, centroid

I am trying to find the centroids of the objects in a grayscale image using python and opencv. I can easily get the center positions of non-overlapping objects as you can see in the following image.

[image]

However, in the same images I have other objects that are overlapping. The code, of course, just considers this overlapped objects as a single one and finds an erroneous centroid. As you can see in this image.[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read image through command line
img = cv2.imread("ExportStack00001.png")

# convert the image to grayscale
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# convert the grayscale image to binary image
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image,1,255,0)

# find contours in the binary image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours:
     # calculate moments for each contour
     M = cv2.moments(c)

    # calculate x,y coordinate of center
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 5, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.putText(img, "centroid", (cX - 25, cY - 25),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # display the image
    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

So I don't really know how to proceed at this point. Which could be the solution?

Comment: These black circles on black background are very difficult to see by eye.  For the example you could had used a different colors.  Anyway I see what you need.  IMHO you need to segment the overlapping circles.  A possible way to do that is to use watershed in scikit-image.
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_watershed.html

Comment: Have a look at Watershed Algorithm here https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html and also consider the *"circularity"* of your shapes to detect overlaps https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/